# FCM generating a new token on every app launch in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Since couple of days facing an issue, firebase generating a new token on every app launch. I couldn't found the reason. Here is my code

```
     public func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool { 
    
           FirebaseApp.configure()
    
           GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
    
           Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    }

    public func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    
           Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    
    }

    public func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    
    }
```

On every app quit and launch creating new one.Help me out to sort this problem

Comment: Where do you call registerForRemoteNotifications() ?

Comment: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions